# Can't format USB storage at /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, ntfs, mkfs

I have an 8GB USB storage and `lsblk` shows it is accessible at /dev/sdb.

When trying to:

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs -L "label" /dev/sdb
```

I got:

```
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!
```

What to do?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-F` option to force mkfs.ntfs to create the file system. See the [mkfs.ntfs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ntfs).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't format a mounted device. umount it.
2. Before you format (mkfs), you have to create partitions. Use fdisk to do it.
3. Then use mkfs on /dev/sdb1 (first partition, for example).
4. Be careful! I hope you are sure /dev/sdb is the correct device.

Comment: the device isn't mounted, doesn't appear anywhere... i think is broken...